# Мягкий знак после согласного перед суффиксом СК ― это орфограмма?

Tags: орфография, мягкий-знак

Речь идет о таких словах: ***июньский, день-деньской, конский, минский, тюменский, сентябрьский, январский.***

Выбор  мягкого знака в них делается **по слуху или по правилу?**

Если это орфограмма, то **какому орфографическому принципу она соответствует**?

Answer (score 3):

[Суффиксы -к- и -ск- в прилагательных](https://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=k_sk_v_sufixah_prilagatelnih)

Примечания:
  • перед -ск- буква ь пишется после л:   сельский, уральский;
  • перед -ск- буква ь пишется в прилагательных, образованных
от названий месяцев на -нь, -рь:   ноябрьский, сентябрьский.

```
  Исключение: январский.  

    В других прилагательных, образованных от существительных на
```

-нь, -рь, мягкий знак не пишется: конь – конский, богатырь – богатырский.

```
  Исключение: день-деньской.
```

**Ь перед -ск-  – это орфограмма.**

Comment: Спасибо большое. Меня в общем-то интересует, можем ли мы написать мягкий знак по слуху во всех приведенных Вами примерах. Дело в том, что звук С здесь твердый, поэтому фонетическое смягчение согласных перед ним исключено. Именно поэтому я сомневаюсь, что это орфограмма, и тогда вся информация, которую надо заучивать, окажется лишней. И какой здесь используется орфографический принцип (это нужно для классификации орфограмм)?

Comment: Кстати, почему Вы так редко заходите на сайт? Здесь мало педагогов, поэтому их мнение всегда интересно, особенно для школьников.